# Time Series: ARIMA vs Random Forest Regressor

Tags: time-series, random-forest, arima

I have two model prediction results:

1. Using ARIMA model

[image: ARIMA predictions]

2. Using Machine learning model where I used Random Forest Regressor
   [image: Random Forest Regressor predictions]

How do we compare these two? Is conventional time series modelling better or, are machine learning methods better?

Comment: Hi Athos, welcome to the community. Please consider upvoting or marking the answer as correct, if you find anything helpful.

Comment: Better at what?

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the model and compare one model with other by calculating accuracy metrics such as - R-squared, root mean squared error, residual standard error, mean absolute error, Adjusted R-squared, AIC, AICc, BIC.

Currently, the most popular metrics for evaluating time series forecasting models are MAE, RMSE and AIC